# Big Data for offline Electron app

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, electron

i got a question about handling Big Data in offline application in Electron.

i made my application which handles a bunch of data (actually a **250MB** Sqlite Database)
i'm handling the sqlite data with *sql.js* library, because the *sqlite npm library* doesent't pass the build phase (even with some tricks found online)

what i'd like to know is if this is the best solution to handle offline data, with update capability.

my app actually connects to my server, syncs with the online database, and allow the user to work offline.
the sync is made by downloading the whole DB every time, because if i perform a massive INSERT statement (even with TRANSACTION, pragma and everything else) the sql.js library hase some issues with memory, and crashes.

now they're asking me to add more data, so the DB size will grow.

is any other option that i may evaluate?!

i was evaluating everything, from localstorage to PouchDB, but i don't want to bring down everything without good reasons...

any help will be appreciated